# Updating four points to stay in a Rectangle shape when one is moved

Tags: c#, gdi, point, angle

I am trying to draw a rectangular object that allows the user to click on a corner-point to resize and also rotate the rectangle in a 2D space.

Therefore I am using an array of four points ordered A, B, C, D (or 0, 1, 2, 3) from top-left to bottom-left in clockwise order.

The rotation works fine, I calculate the center point and rotate each point around it by an angle.

The resizing is done by determining which point was pressed down, and then setting its new position to the position of the mouse on each MouseMove event.  The two adjacent points then need to be updated to stay in a rectangular shape.  The resizing is intermittently not working.  I have tried many ways to error-check, but all leave me with the same problem where if I move the mouse back and forth over the opposing point while moving a point, the points get distorted and are no longer a rectangular shape.

**SOURCE CODE HERE**

https://www.assembla.com/code/moozhe-testing/subversion/nodes/rotateRectangle

**EXERPT OF PROBLEM CODE**

```
private void MovePoint(int id, PointF newPoint)
{
    PointF oldPoint = points[id];
    PointF delta = newPoint.Substract(oldPoint);

    PointF pointPrevious = points[(id + 3) % 4];
    PointF pointNext = points[(id + 1) % 4];

    PointF sidePrevious = pointPrevious.Substract(oldPoint);
    PointF sideNext = pointNext.Substract(oldPoint);

    PointF previousProjection = Projection(delta, sidePrevious);
    PointF nextProjection = Projection(delta, sideNext);

    pointNext = pointNext.AddPoints(previousProjection);
    pointPrevious = pointPrevious.AddPoints(nextProjection);

    points[(id + 3) % 4] = pointPrevious;
    points[(id + 1) % 4] = pointNext;
    points[id] = newPoint;
}

private PointF Projection(PointF vectorA, PointF vectorB)
{
    PointF vectorBUnit = new PointF(vectorB.X, vectorB.Y);
    vectorBUnit = vectorBUnit.Normalize();

    float dotProduct = vectorA.X * vectorBUnit.X + vectorA.Y * vectorBUnit.Y;
    return vectorBUnit.MultiplyByDecimal(dotProduct);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to be using a transformation matrix, instead of updating X/Y coordinates manually.  Please check out this link:

[Comparing GDI mapping modes with GDI+ transforms](https://web.archive.org/web/20120718030334/http://www.bobpowell.net/mappingmodes.htm)

Here's the MSDN reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.transform

Comment: I use matrix transforms for drawing, but not for translating user input.  I need to be able to detect if a particular point is clicked.  Not everything is going to be rotated, I could have many objects each on their own rotation angles.  Is there a feasible way for me to do that?  Aren't I going to end up doing the same math, only on the fly instead of in advance?